# iPhone SDK: How to dismiss keyboard each time user moves to new field

Tags: iphone

We want the keyboard to be dismissed each time the user moves to a new field. What event would be appropriate to place a resignFirstResponder call?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your most likely looking for the `textFieldShouldReturn` delegate

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField;
```

Comment: For some reason textFieldShouldReturn is not being called. I checked the delegate is set in IB and the UITextFieldDelegate is adopted. What could be missing?

Comment: yourTextField.delegate = self;

Answer (score 0):

Use the appropriate `UITextFieldDelegate` method:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder]
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: For some reason textFieldShouldReturn is not being called. I checked the delegate is set in IB and the UITextFieldDelegate is adopted.